# Where to include additional stylesheets in my template?

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

Im struggling to include the following stylesheets in my template. Which file do i need to load them in?

```
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/templates/gk_simplicity/css/social.css');
    $doc->addStyleSheet( '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

It seems that no matter where i add the code, neither are showing as loading in the < head > tag when i inspect the source, the font-awesome icons aren't rendering correctly either? I have implemented the code fine manually on a subdomain, so i know i do not need to include any additional files, other than those mentioned above.

Any suggestions?
Regards
Donna

Comment: Would you care to follow up with this? Abandoned questions are ugly. Did we solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add it directly to your template's index file you might be better off using the `JHtml::stylesheet` method:

```
<?php
   JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::base() . 'templates/gk_simplicity/css/sample.css', true);
?>
```

What you have there is intended to be used inside template functions.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

Comment: Ok, i have tried that method too, placed it in the Index.php file, but still they are not loading? I'm baffled. I've sent a message to the template developer to see if they can shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through some of the Gavick Pro documentation, I believe you will need to firstly put all your font files in the following directory:

```
templates/gk_simplicity/css/
```

---

Once done, in the Template settings, set **CSS Override** to **Enabled**

---

Then, copy and paste the code from your `social.css` into the `override.css` file that they provide you with or the textarea named "**Custom CSS Code**"

---

Using this method to *override* what is already there, rather than *alter* it, means that your changes will not be lot in a template update